# What happens when an executor is lost?

Tags: apache-spark

I get these messages:

```
16/05/22 13:33:53 ERROR YarnScheduler: Lost executor 61 on <host>: Executor heartbeat timed out after 134828 ms
16/05/22 13:33:53 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 25.0 in stage 12.0 (TID 2214, <host>): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 61 lost)
```

Will a replacement executor be spawned?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Will a replacement executor be spawned?

Yes, it will. Sparks `DAGScheduler` and it's lower level cluster manager implementation (Standalone, YARN or Mesos) will notice a task failed and will take care of rescheduling the said task as part of the overall stages executed.

[image: DAGScheduler]

> DAGScheduler does three things in Spark (thorough explanations follow):
>
> - Computes an execution DAG, i.e. DAG of stages, for a job.
> - Determines the preferred locations to run each task on.
> - Handles failures due to shuffle output files being lost.

For more on that you can find in [Advanced Spark Tutorial](https://databricks-training.s3.amazonaws.com/slides/advanced-spark-training.pdf) and in [Mastering Apache Spark](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/spark-dagscheduler.html).

Answer (score 5):

#### Yes. It will try to resubmit the lost executor and will be trying to replay that. Please see below log..

```
16/02/27 21:37:01 ERROR cluster.YarnScheduler: Lost executor 6 on
ip-10-0-0-156.ec2.internal: remote Akka client disassociated
16/02/27 21:37:01 WARN remote.ReliableDeliverySupervisor:
Association with remote system [akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@ip-10-0-0-
156.ec2.internal:39097]
has failed, address is now gated for [5000] ms. Reason is:
[Disassociated].
16/02/27 21:37:01 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Re-queueing tasks
for 6 from TaskSet 1.0
16/02/27 21:37:01 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Resubmitted
ShuffleMapTask(1, 92), so marking it as still running
16/02/27 21:37:01 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Resubmitted
ShuffleMapTask(1, 88), so marking it as still running
16/02/27 21:37:01 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 146.0
in stage 1.0 (TID 1151, ip-10-0-0-156.ec2.internal): ExecutorLostFailure
(executor 6
lost)
16/02/27 21:37:01 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Resubmitted
ShuffleMapTask(1, 93), so marking it as still running
16/02/27 21:37:01 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Resubmitted
ShuffleMapTask(1, 89), so marking it as still running
16/02/27 21:37:01 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Resubmitted
ShuffleMapTask(1, 87), so marking it as still running
16/02/27 21:37:01 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Resubmitted
ShuffleMapTask(1, 90), so marking it as still running
16/02/27 21:37:01 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Resubmitted
ShuffleMapTask(1, 91), so marking it as still running
16/02/27 21:37:01 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Resubmitted
ShuffleMapTask(1, 85), so marking it as still running
16/02/27 21:37:01 INFO storage.BlockManagerMasterActor: Trying to
remove executor 6 from BlockManagerMaster.
16/02/27 21:37:02 INFO storage.BlockManagerMasterActor: Removing
block manager BlockManagerId(6, ip-10-0-0-156.ec2.internal, 34952)
16/02/27 21:37:02 INFO storage.BlockManagerMaster: Removed 6
successfully in removeExecutor
16/02/27 21:37:02 INFO scheduler.Stage: Stage 1 is now unavailable
on executor 6 (536/598, false)
16/02/27 21:37:17 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task
146.1 in stage 1.0 (TID 1152, ip-10-0-0-154.ec2.internal, RACK_LOCAL,
1396 bytes)
16/02/27 21:37:17 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 123.0
in stage 1.0 (TID 1148, ip-10-0-0-154.ec2.internal): java.io.IOException:
Failed to
connect to ip-10-0-0-156.ec2.internal/10.0.0.156:34952
16/02/27 21:37:01 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Resubmitted
ShuffleMapTask(1, 86), so marking it as still running
16/02/27 21:37:01 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Resubmitted
ShuffleMapTask(1, 94), so marking it as still running
16/02/27 21:37:01 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Executor lost: 6
(epoch 0)
```

**Fix** is to increase `spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead` until this goes away.  This controls the buffer between the JVM heap size and the amount of
memory requested from YARN (JVMs can take up memory beyond their heap
size). You also make sure that, in the YARN NodeManager
configuration, `yarn.nodemanager.vmem-check-enabled` is set to false.
Reason for false is , it will prevent the NM to keep control over the containers.
If you are running out of physical memory in a container make sure that the JVM heap size is small enough to fit in the container.

See the below diagram to understand it better.

[image]
The container size should be large enough to contain:

- JVM heap
- permanent generation for the JVM
- any off-heap allocations

In most cases an overhead of between 15%-30% of the JVM heap will suffice. Your job configuration should include the proper JVM and container settings.
Some jobs will require more and some will require less overhead.

Comment: I already set `spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead` to 3000. Why do I need to disable `yarn.nodemanager.vmem-check-enabled`?

Comment: @sds updated answer... These were the settings, which were applied by us to resolve the issue. Moreover, it was recommendation by cloudera employee.